# openni camera launch multikinect

Tags: kinect, roslaunch, openni, camera, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using multiple kinects.
and I want to address the kinect fix by referring to the bus which the kinects are connected. I think i should do something like this to refer the bus (e.g. bus 2) in the openni_node launch file:

but it doesn't work. Help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Kang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11288/openni-camera-launch-multikinect/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-09-23**:
When asking a question, please specify what version of the software you're using (e.g. Diamondback) and copy/paste all error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"002" is not a recognized format for device_id. Examples are given in comments in the openni_node.launch file.

The easiest way to get up and running is to use device IDs "#1", "#2", etc., which opens the first/second enumerated Kinect. Another format, closer to what you're trying to do, is "2@3", which opens the device on USB bus 2, address 3. Enumeration order and USB address can both change when you unplug/replug a Kinect however.

To make your launch configuration repeatable, use the Kinect serial number as the device_id. The driver prints the serial number to console when you open the device, so you can collect these by opening with "#1" etc. It'll look something like "B00367707227042B".

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-09-26**:
When you connect a USB device, the host assigns it a unique 7-bit address. This address is basically arbitrary. To open multiple Kinects in a repeatable way, open them by serial number.

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-09-25**:
Thanks Patrick for the reply. Usually I use enumeration which is the easiest way. But now I need to make it fix for addressing. Btw, for '2@3', '2' is bus, and what is address '3' here? port? and this also can change if the device is plug/unplug?